# Setting $_SESSION variables at page change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using two `$_SESSION` variables on one of my web pages. These are extremely crucial as they control how data is manipulated. Right now, when the user leaves that page and loads another, I'm resetting the two `$_SESSION variables = 0` on each loading page.

**My question:**
Is there a way, maybe in **JQuery** or something, that I can detect when a user leaves that web page for another and then reset the variables that way, instead of doing it across some 50 pages as I'm doing now? To me, this would be a cleaner approach.

At the top of every page but the one in question, this is what I'm doing using PHP to reset the two variables:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['var1'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['var2'] = 0;
?>
```

Comment: Provide the code That you have tried from your side

Comment: I haven't tried any code because I don't know how to do what I'm asking. Not that it cld possibly be helpful to what I'm asking, but if you're talking about how I'm currently resetting the $_SESSION vars, then I'll make an edit and post that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of doing this in `PHP` would be to have a "header" file which you include on every single page IMHO:

```
<?php
    include_once "header.inc.php";
    // .....
?>
```

Such a header file is usually used to manage database-connections and also session-variables like in your case.
By starting every single page with including this header file, you can easily change "global stuff" later on.

Comment: low-rents: Thank you. I'm not using that reset code in an include file, but doing it that way isn't a bad idea. I just read about the include / include_once differences. I may be able to to zero out the two variables on that page only using include_once and eliminate having to use it on all the other pages. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: @Landslyde you are welcome. and be careful, `include_once` does nothing magical - it just makes sure that a file is only included once if you got multiple includes on the same page (or in included files). if you are doing sensitive stuff (like checking login-credentials) in your header file, you should rather use `require_once` which stops the execution of any further PHP code if the inclusion fails.